# How to set up LPD/LPR printing system for sharing a postscript printer on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, printer, printing, network-shares

I am new in Embedded Systems, and I want to add a usb postscript printing support such that it can serve request from any computer in the Network(Printer sharing).

I went through various printing protocols and found that I can achieve this by using the LPD/LPR printing protocol.

But I couldn't find the exact procedure/setup required for printer sharing?

So please help me through this.
(This is my first assignment in this company and I want it to be perfect and in time.)

Thanks for the suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using [IPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol) for this, and you want [CUPS](http://www.cups.org/) for that. Install CUPS, open port 631 on the device, configure CUPS for remote HTTP connections (its config file looks *just* like a HTTPd config file, with a few CUPS-specific options added), then connect to port 631 with a browser and add and configure your printers there.

Note that CUPS also gives you the option of sharing printers via SMB and even LPR if so required.

Also consider installing [Avahi](http://avahi.org/) in order to provide [Zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) access to the printer(s) from OS X and *nix (and Windows with [Bonjour Print Services](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl999) installed).

Comment: Thanks Ignacio,

correct me if I am wrong at any point.

 Is it possible to not use cups?

 As memory footprint of CUPS is much more larger than that of LPD/LPD printing spooler.

 And I found that there are some china products in which those guys are using LPD/LPR for
 Printer sharing in network.
 You can find it at http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/553515374/Networking_USB_2_0_Print_Server.html

(continued in following comment).

Comment: And also found that postscript print is possible using LPD/LPR as follows : 
  > When Print is given, computer spools the print job to disk and generates the PostScript 
    data (the data file).
  > Then it sends the data file and control file to the IP address specified in the LPR 
    desktop printer.

So please tell me that is it possible to add a USB postscript printer support, such that it can be shared by all the computers in the network using LPD/LPR printing spooler?

Thank You.

Comment: My Pogoplug has a RSS of 3048 kB for cupsd and a further 1068 kB for avahi-daemon, which is not terrible all things considered.